# Why the hover-effect of Chrome icon on the Chrome download page isn't css3 based

Tags: css

Today I notice the hover-effect icon on the Chrome download page([chrome](http://chrome.google.com)) . Is very cool.
I noticed the use css3 combine js to achieve this effect, as the code below:

```
    function maskImg() {
        var requestAnimationFrame = window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame,
                startTime = window.mozAnimationStartTime || Date.now();
        var MAX = 138, img = this, maxTime = 1500;
        requestAnimationFrame(function (timestamp) {
            var drawStart = (timestamp || Date.now()),
                    diff = drawStart - startTime;
            img.style.cssText = ['-webkit-mask: -webkit-gradient(radial, 17 17, ' ,
                Math.floor(diff * MAX / maxTime) ,
                ', 17 17, ' ,
                Math.floor(diff * MAX / maxTime) +15,
                ', from(rgb(0, 0, 0)), color-stop(0.5, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), to(rgb(0, 0, 0)));'].join('');
            if (maxTime > diff)requestAnimationFrame(arguments.callee);
        });
    }
```

And I wonder if I can achieve the same purpose with webkit-animation and @-webkit-keyframes and -webkit-mask, but I fail, as the code on [link](http://jsbin.com/efikuq/1).
I'm asking why and how I can do to achieve this. If you can tell me the reason behind this, it will be great.

My english is very poor, sorry about that.

Comment: Just being curious: what didn't you like about my answer ? :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what makes you think you are failing. Your animation does work: you can see a "glare" on letter 'm' when you place your mouse over the image.

### Why doesn't it work

What makes your animation not at all impressive is the fact that you only define 3 keyframes:

- **at 0%**: You never get the chance to see this one: It sets a starting point, but as soon as the animation begins you are past 0%, so it moves on to the next keyframe. Changing that to e.g. 5% would make it observable.
- **at 50%**: That's the "glare" we can observe on letter 'm' (it is actually the only *visual* indication that your animation is working).
- **at 100%**: You set the radius at 138px on an image that is only 123px wide, so naturally we can't observe anything.

### How to make it work

In order to make it work, you need to specify more keyframes (since the `-webkit-mask-image` property is **not** on the **[list of animatable CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FCSS_animated_properties)**).
For that reason, it is probably not a good idea to implement such an animation using CSS. Just imagine having to define 50 keyframes for webkit browsers, 50 for firefox, 50 for IE and so on. Defining less keyframes would result in a less smooth animation.
On the other hand, you only need to define **1 function** (as opposed to 50 keyframes!) for each browser in JavaScript.

---

I have prepared a **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/x7ths/embedded/result/)**, which features a CSS-powered and a JS-powered hover effect on identical images, to showcase the differences in smoothness and lines of code. (I defined 21 keyframes in CSS. Also, since it is just a demo, I have made it webkit-compatible only.)

Some stats:

```
     | keyframes | lines of code
-----+-----------+---------------
 CSS |    21     |     ~150
  JS |    50     |      ~25
```

The source-code for the demo can be found **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/x7ths/)**.

---

### Conclusion

It can be done using both CSS or JS.
But JS is shorter and smoother !

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of cool, too bad it's not cross browser compatible.  You could probably achieve the same effect with an animation and be more cross browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Because the frames is grained larger than js ,css is not subtle.